# Windows server 2012

Tags: windows, сервер

Есть рабочая группа - Workgroup. Я создал домен, который пришлось удалить, так как в нем, как оказалось, не было необходимости. Так теперь я не могу логиниться под пользователями, которые были до создания домена. Они есть в папке пользователей, в корне основного диска. Мне нужно пересоздавать всех заново или можно как-то вернуть их обратно?

Comment: Нужно вывести этих пользователей из домена, сделать локальными. Если там ничего, кроме документов, нет - проще пересоздать и переместить документы. Потому как ковыряться с ошмётками доменных политик в профиле - то ещё развлечение.

Comment: а каким образом я могу их вывести если я вижу только их папки, а в пользователях и группах их нет?

Comment: Вариант решения. 0) Делаем резервную копию. 1) Создаём нового локального пользователя. 2) В его свойствах указываем в качестве каталога профиля "старый" каталог. 3) Пробуем зайти этим пользователем.

Comment: Не помогло. Хотя каталог он принял, так как не добавил после пользователя VMD873C3B, как в случаем с моим пользователем, но какталоги и прочую хрень он не перенес У меня два пользователя Админа. 1)Administrator.VMD873C3B, и просто Administrator, хотя из доменного имени я исключился

Comment: пересоздавать заново, и желательно было сделать это до удаления домена